# How do i set up lighting to photograph a bunch of shoes for a website?

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting, product-photography, reflection

I have a couple of shoes I need to shoot- what would be the most effective way to set up my lights to get well lit products. Many of the shoes are highly reflective which adds an additional challenge to the setup.

(my equipment- canon rebel, 18-55, 55-250, 2 monolights, various reflectors, diffusers & lightstands)

Comment: A sample of what you've tried will get you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set up a plexiglass for a table then you can arrange one light from underneath and one from the top with diffusion paper or a scrim to soften the light and then use silver or white cardboard around the shoes to bounce more light around or block out reflections

Comment: any ideas how i can prop up the plexi?

Comment: @Pastel - The "real deal" is a shooting table, but if you have a couple of boxes of the appropriate height or even a pair of standard dining chairs you can just lay the plexi between them. A lot of people I know are using one of those X-shaped folding keyboard stands for a quick-and-dirty version; they're relatively cheap at music and consumer electronics shops.

Comment: @StanRogers the keyboard stand is a great idea esp since i have one for my piano, thanx for the ideas

Answer (score 1):

If you have shiny shoes, a softbox or large diffused light source will help with showcasing the shape and shine of your shoes, if you want that effect.

The main thing is to get the setup in place for capturing the shoes properly and similarly exposed/posed. Then you can just place shoes, shoot, replace, shoot, etc.

A light tent would work. Two softboxes would work.

I would opt to avoid umbrellas as the ribs and pointed edges would show up in the reflection highlights and may be off putting.